# retrieving multiple (transformed) values in mongodb group matching a criterion from the group itself

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, time-series, nosql

I am finding my way through mongodb and have a collection that contains some documents of this shape:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("547a13b70dc5d228db81c475"),
"INSTRUMENT" : "InstrumentA",
"BID" : 5287,
"ASK" : 5290,
"TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2014-10-01T23:57:27.137Z")
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("547a0da20dc5d228db2f034d"),
"INSTRUMENT" : "InstrumentB",
"BID" : 0.88078,
"ASK" : 0.88098,
"TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2014-10-01T23:58:59.637Z")
}
```

What I am looking to get is the last known mid `(BID + ASK)/2` before a given ISODate for each `INSTRUMENT`. I got as far as getting the time of the last information across instruments and the last value of that last instrument. Even though the following looks like it works, the `lastOccurance` is being polluted across instruments.

```
   db.runCommand(
   {
     group:
       {
         ns: 'collectionTest',
         key : { INSTRUMENT : 1}   ,
         cond: { TIMESTAMP: { $lte: ISODate("2014-10-01 08:30:00") } }  ,
         $reduce: function( curr, result ) {
                      if(curr.TIMESTAMP > result.lastOccurance)
                      {  
                        result.lastOccurance = curr.TIMESTAMP;
                        result.MID = (curr.BID + curr.ASK)/2;
                        result.INSTRUMENT = curr.INSTRUMENT;  
                      }else
                      {
                        result.lastOccurance = null;
                        result.MID = null;
                        result.INSTRUMENT = null;  
                      }
                  },
         initial: { lastOccurance : ISODate("1900-01-01 00:00:00") }
       }
   }
)
```

If anybody can see a fix for this code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) instead of `group` whenever possible because it provides better performance and supports sharding.

With `aggregate` you can do this as:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Only include the docs prior to the given date
    {$match: {TIMESTAMP: { $lte: ISODate("2014-10-01 08:30:00") }}},
    // Sort them in descending TIMESTAMP order
    {$sort: {TIMESTAMP: -1}},
    // Group them by INSTRUMENT, taking the first one in each group (which will be
    // the last one before the given date) and computing the MID value for it.
    {$group: {
        _id: '$INSTRUMENT', 
        MID: {$first: {$divide: [{$add: ['$BID', '$ASK']}, 2]}},
        lastOccurance : {$first: '$TIMESTAMP'}
    }}
])
```